# Ни/не того(,) ни/не другого

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Я не видел ни того ни другого  (НЕ или НИ, запятая нужна ?)

Answer (score 3):

Ни того ни другого - устойчивое выражение, запятую не ставим. Пишем НИ, усиливающую отрицание.

Правда, я не раз встречала это выражение, оформленное с запятой. Вероятно, это зависит от произношения, от наличия-отсутствия выразительной паузы между однородными членами.

Answer (score 3):

Я не видел ни того ни другого.

В данном  выражении используется соединительный повторяющийся союз НИ...НИ с усилительной частицей НИ (аналог союза И...И в утвердительных предложениях).

Вообще говоря, в устойчивых выражениях запятая не ставится вследствие тесного смыслового единства слов, однако в данном случае вопрос о тесном единстве решает автор:

(1) Бог не дал ей ни того ни другого.

(2) Я не стал дожидаться ни того, ни другого.